# Jimmy's back, and trying

Tags: cipher

Continuing along the 'lines' of this puzzle - [Such a simple task!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94346/such-a-simple-task)

This time around Darlene couldn't be happier. Jimmy managed to build the pig pen to the specs he was given, but he still doesn't know what it says! Seems like Darlene is having some fun with him - can you help Jimmy find out what his own creation is saying?

[image]

Should be a breeze for experienced SE puzzlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message reads:

> **Someday I'll figure this out.**

It is solved by:

> Using the same pigpen cipher grid from the earlier linked puzzle,
>  [image: pig]
>  the symbols transcribe to: 
>  FBZRQNL
>  VYY
>  SVTHER
>  GUVF
>  BHG
>  Applying a ROT13 to this gives 'SOMEDAY ILL FIGURE THIS OUT'